# matching patterns between columns

Tags: awk, sed

The data is

```
   id    ecid  go1           go2
 GLY1   GLY21  Go:021        Go:022,Go:021
 GLY2   GLY32  Go:031,Go:023 Go:023,Go:021
 GLY5   GLY3   Go:012,Go:021 Go:021 
 GLY6   GLY7   Go:021        Go:021
```

and I want to match patterns between two columns and tried

```
awk '($3 == "Go:021") && ($4 == "Go:021")' trial.txt
```

This only lists

```
GLY6   GLY7   Go:021    Go:021
```

But I would like other columns which contain the matching patterns as well

```
GLY1   GLY21  Go:021        Go:022,Go:021
GLY5   GLY3   Go:012,Go:021 Go:021 
GLY6   GLY7   Go:021        Go:021
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use pattern match instead

```
$ awk '$3~/Go:021/ && $4~/Go:021/' file
 GLY1   GLY21  Go:021        Go:022,Go:021
 GLY5   GLY3   Go:012,Go:021 Go:021
 GLY6   GLY7   Go:021        Go:021
```

Comment: ya this probably nicer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need this to remove redundancy and avoid false matches:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{p="(^|,)Go:021(,|$)"} $3~p && $4~p' file
 GLY1   GLY21  Go:021        Go:022,Go:021
 GLY5   GLY3   Go:012,Go:021 Go:021
 GLY6   GLY7   Go:021        Go:021
```

To keep the header line:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{p="(^|,)Go:021(,|$)"} (NR==1) || ($3~p && $4~p)' file
   id    ecid  go1           go2
 GLY1   GLY21  Go:021        Go:022,Go:021
 GLY5   GLY3   Go:012,Go:021 Go:021
 GLY6   GLY7   Go:021        Go:021
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk '/ Go:021 .* Go:021 /{print $0}' trial.txt`